# Is it possible to manually set a django foreignkey ID to an item that doesn't exist yet?

Tags: python, django

I'm designing a bulk import tool from an old system into a new Django based system.

I'd like to retain all of the current IDs of objects (they are just 5 digit strings), now due to the design in the current system there are lots of references between these objects.

To import I can see 2 possible techniques - import a known object, and carefully recurse through these relationships making sure to import in the right way and only set relationships as soon as I know they exist

... or start at item `00001` set the foreignkeys to values I know exist and just grab everything in order, knowing that once we get to item `99999` all the relationships will exist.

So is there a way to set a foreignkey to the ID of an item that doesn't exist, but will, even for imports only?

To add further complexity, not all of these relationships are straightforward foreignkeys, some are `ManyToMany` relationships as well.

Comment: What database backend is Django running?

Comment: At the moment SQLite, but I'm trying to make it abstract enough to run on any DB django supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to handle any database that Django supports and not have to deal with peculiarities of the backend, I'd export the old database in the format that Django [`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) can read, and then give this exported file to `loaddata`. This command has no issue importing the type of structure you are talking about.

Creating the file that `loaddata` will read could be done by writing your own converter that reads the old database and dumps an appropriate file. However, a way which *might* be easier would be to create a throwaway Django project with models that have the same structure as the tables in the old database, point the Django project to the old database, and use [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata) to create the file. If table details between the old database and the new database have changed, you'd still have to modify the file but at least some of the conversion work would have already been done.

A more direct way would be to bypass Django completely to do the import in SQL but turn off foreign key constraints for the time of the import. For MySQL this would be done by setting [foreign_key_checks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) to 0 for the time of the import, and then back to 1 when done. For SQLite this would be [done by using](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) `PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;` and then `ON` when done.

Postgresql does not allow just turning off these constraints but Django creates foreign key constraints as `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`, which means that the constraint is not checked until the end of a transaction. So initiating a transaction, importing and then committing should work. If something prevents this, then you have to drop the constraint before importing and add it back afterwards.

Comment: As an XY Problem, get an XY answer. This is indeed what I should be doing instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a database migration tool [like South](http://south.aeracode.org/), the standard for Django. Worth noting that [Django 1.7 Beta 1](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2014/mar/20/django-17b1/) was released recently and it provides in-built migration.